# Orchard get razor views from database

Tags: razor, orchardcms-1.6

I am writing a custom orchard module which needs to read in "Razor template" views from the database and dynamically add them to orchard pages when published via Content manager.

I see that Orchard implements its own view engine and also a custom virtualPathHandler. I am wondering if someone has tried to do something similar in orchard.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change the layout of your page at runtime for that you want to use Razor templates. You can probably use the layout selector module from gallery and change the layout of a page on runtime using it. 
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.M33.Layout

Comment: Thanks Praggie. I am also opting for razor template. I want to be able to read in the template from db or a string and render that as a ad-hoc view within the page. Being new to orchard, I am still trying to figure out how the shapehelper thing works and if I can use it to create shapes from template dynamically. Thanks for the suggestions on the module - I will give it a try.